# Android GalleryView Problem

Tags: android, galleryview

I have a problem with android galleryview, in my app I have a lot of pictures. And I wanna display them by gallerview and make them selectable. I figured out displaying them horizontal scrollable and make them selectable with Galleryview, but I need one image on the screen at a time, after horizontal  scrolling the scrollbar by the user, another picture must be shown. My test code is below and this shows 3 pictures on the screen, from http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-example:

```
        package com.projects.cards;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Gallery;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class GaleryTestActivity extends Activity {

private Gallery gallery;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.galery);

    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Displaying the position when the gallery item in clicked
            Toast.makeText(GaleryTestActivity.this, "Position=" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    // Adding images.
    private Integer[] Imgid = {
            R.drawable.a_1, R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_3, R.drawable.a_4, R.drawable.a_5, R.drawable.a_6, R.drawable.a_7
    };

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
        // Fixing width & height for image to display
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 160));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return imgView;
    }
}
```

}

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want the currently focused image to take up all the screen space. You can achieve this by setting the width of the ImageView where you bind it to the Gallery (in getView). Try setting the width of the image to match the width of the device screen.

Note that you can also set the spacing between the items in the Gallery with the gallery.setSpacing(...) method.

I can not tell you how to show a scrollbar, sorry.

Comment: All I need is just spacing! gallery.setSpacing(100); then at a time I see one image on the screen. Also I don't need a visible scrollbar, if a touching event occurrs, android os handles scrolling for me, special thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can try returning view with fill parent as its width which contains your imageview from your adapters getView() ...

Or alse  you can do something like this

getview function

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater iteminflater = LayoutInflater.from(cont);
    View gallaryitem = iteminflater .inflate(R.layout.gallaryitem, null);
    ImageView imgView= (ImageView ) gallaryitem .findViewById(R.id.image);
    imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
    gallaryitem .setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);
    return gallaryitem ;
    }
```

gallaryitem.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
       <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                     android:orientation="horizontal" 
                     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"   
                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

           <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                      android:id="@+id/image" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                      android:src="@drawable/icon"   
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

           </ImageView>
       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented gallery view like, one that is mentioned in the below in the link. Please try that also: [Android gallery with caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448107/android-gallery-with-caption/6449937#6449937)

Comment: Your implementation is not different than mine. I need a scrollbar and one image at a time on the screen.