# Newbie: gallery show only one image each time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I have followed the android [gallery tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) to build a simple gallery which is exactly the same as the tutorial's.

Now, I would like to improve the gallery from the tutorial to show only **one** image at **one time**(in the tutorial, several images are showing at once), that's only show one image which occupy the whole gallery area.

Then, only finger touch and move the current image to left or right will make the neighboring next(left or right) image to be shown.

How should I modify the tutorial's code? any suggestions?

Comment: another Gallery/ImageView tutorial: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example
You could start a new Activity with only an ImageView (whole screensize) using onClickListener/onTouchListener

Comment: @Milde, the tutorial is the same for me, I want the top slide part show only one image at one time not a serial of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the Image the same size as the screen:

```
i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(Gallery.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gallery.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: is there any way to only have the same size as the screen horizontally, NOT vertically?? Because I have other views under the gallery.

Comment: @Leem you can pass the values to Gallery.LayoutParams(int w, int h), see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.LayoutParams.html#Gallery.LayoutParams%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

This thread might be useful

[Android GalleryView Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503544/android-galleryview-problem/6503751#6503751)