# How to place a textview on Gallery in android?

Tags: android, android-gallery

In my application i have gallery view , i am displaying images from database in gallery,i need to place a text view on gallery item and change the text view value based on gallery position.So,how i can place text view on gallery.please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: Use custom adapter and custom layout for gallery items.For eg: refer http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-custom-gallery-application.html

Answer (score 0):

Use custom adapter for you gallery view. Every item will contain an ImageView and also a TextView, for example in a RelativeLayout.

Example here: [Android gallery with caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448107/android-gallery-with-caption/6449937#6449937)